# defaultUserNotificationCenter causing 'unrecognized selector' error in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, nsusernotificationcenter

I am trying to access `defaultUserNotificationCenter` in my C++ application and I cannot seem to get this working.  The code below is causing the error:

> [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance $memory-location-to-notifCenter

with the exception being raised at the last line.

```
id notifCenter = (id)objc_getClass("NSUserNotificationCenter");
notifCenter = objc_msgSend(notifCenter, sel_registerName("alloc"));
notifCenter = objc_msgSend(notifCenter, sel_registerName("defaultUserNotificationCenter"));
```

I have tried this without `alloc`ing `notifCenter` however this causes `notifCenter` to be nil even before I get to `...defaultUser...` with or without an Info.plist file containing a Bundle Identifier.

Just to make sure nothing crazy happens behind the scenes with `defaultUserNotificationCenter` I wrote a small Obj-C program to do the same (`NSUserNotificationCenter *defNotifCenter = [NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter];)` and loaded it up in Hopper to check the assembly and it showed:

```
    mov  rsi, qword [0x100001128] ;@selector(defaultUserNotificationCenter)
    mov  rdi, qword [objc_cls_ref_NSUserNotificationCenter]
    call imp___stubs__objc_msgSend
```

This shows nothing out of the ordinary happening at the system level so now I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Do you want to use [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]?

Comment: @Land NSNotificationCenter is for sending notifications between threads so not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use an Objective-C++ class? Then you could use Objective-C with C++... using objc_msgSend directly is not a great idea.

Comment: @AdamKaplan This is part of a POC side project I am working on. No other reason than to experiment and learn ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `alloc` on an Objective-C class, you'll get back a pointer to a new **instance** of that class.

```
id notifCenter = (id)objc_getClass("NSUserNotificationCenter");
notifCenter = objc_msgSend(notifCenter, sel_registerName("alloc"));
```

At this point, `notifCenter` has been reassigned to a new instance of `NSUserNotificationCenter`. It is no longer a reference to the Class instance and no longer has access to the Class methods.

```
notifCenter = objc_msgSend(notifCenter, sel_registerName("defaultUserNotificationCenter"));
```

Now you're calling a **class** method on an **instance** of that class. You can only call instance methods on an instance, and class methods on a Class instance.

I think that this will work if you just remove the middle line (the line with `alloc`).

I also think you should explore Objective-C++, using .mm files. It's pretty nice to use Objective-C itself and not directly drive the runtime.

Comment: This was it. I cannot believe I just forgot to wrap the `objc_getClass` call with `objc_msgSend`. Great write-up!